# Finding a pattern inside a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python.

I have a string printing a table(and its contents) just like the following

```
Name         At time Last  Inter\ Max    Logfile Location               Status  
                     time   val   log                                           
                           (mins) files                                         
------------ ------- ----- ------ ------ ------------------------------ ------- 
foo1           now   16:00   60   100    flash:/schedule/foo1/          Job     
                                                                        under   
                                                                        progress
foo2           now     -     60   100    -                              Waiting 
tech-support   now   16:00   60   100    flash:/schedule/tech-support/  Job     
                                                                        under   
                                                                        progress
```

I need to find how many times the string "`Job under progress`" is present in the table. I tried `len( re.findall( pattern, string ) )` and `len( re.findall("(?=%s)" % pattern, string) )` but none of them seem to work.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Is that the exact format? Is the line `Job under progress` (in one line), rather than broken up in three lines as in your example?

Comment: If I am not wrong its one line. Whole row is inserted using table.newRow(..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = """
Name         At time Last  Inter\ Max    Logfile Location               Status  
                     time   val   log                                           
                           (mins) files                                         
------------ ------- ----- ------ ------ ------------------------------ ------- 
foo1           now   16:00   60   100    flash:/schedule/foo1/          Job     
                                                                        under   
                                                                        progress
foo2           now     -     60   100    -                              Waiting 
tech-support   now   16:00   60   100    flash:/schedule/tech-support/  Job     
                                                                        under   
                                                                        progress
                                                                        """
import re
print len(re.findall("Job\s+under\s+progress", data))
```

**Output**

```
2
```

**Edit:**
If its in the same line, you dont need regEx at all

```
data = """
Name         At time Last  Inter\ Max    Logfile Location               Status  
                     time   val   log                                           
                           (mins) files                                         
------------ ------- ----- ------ ------ ------------------------------ ------- 
foo1           now   16:00   60   100    flash:/schedule/foo1/          Job under progress
foo2           now     -     60   100    -                              Waiting 
tech-support   now   16:00   60   100    flash:/schedule/tech-support/  Job under progress
"""

print sum(1 for line in data.split("\n") if "Job under progress" in line)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

Comment: picky, but i would use `+` here.

Comment: @Eevee You are right. There will be atleast one whitespace character.